# Excel Userform Listbox add selected to worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using this code to add selected items from listbox to worksheet. It is adding selected items to the sheet but it places it in the sheet row of the position it is in the listbox. I want it to start at A1 and then stack the selected items A2, A3 etc regardless of the position in the listbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rRange As Range
Dim lCount As Long   'Counter

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

Set rRange = Range("A1")

With ListBox1
   For lCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(lCount) = True Then
         rRange.Offset(lCount, 0).Value = .List(lCount)
      End If
   Next
End With

BeforeExit:
Set rRange = Nothing
'Unload Me

Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code:

```
    'Set rRange = Range("A1") 'Not necessary

    lMyRow = 1 'Dim as long
    With ListBox1
        For lCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(lCount) = True Then
                Worksheets("NameOfYourSheet").Cells(lMyRow, 1).Value = .List(lCount)
                lMyRow = lMyRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: this works but the data is not stacking when added to the sheet, it is just being replaced in A1